# How to append new rows using cvs files?

Tags: list, python-2.7, csv

```
import csv

running = 1

def show_menu():
    print "1. Add"
    print "2. check"
    return input("Please make a selection: ")

def add():
       writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
       writer.writeheader()
       writer.writerow({'username': raw_input('Uid:'), 'password': raw_input('Pass:')})
       print "success!"
       running = 0

while running:
    choice = show_menu()
    if choice == 1:
        with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
           fieldnames = ['username', 'password']
           add()
```

The next input I add is overwriting the existing ones. How do I append the new input to the old ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to append, you can open the file in append mode.

```
open('names.csv', 'a')
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped !
Can you tell me how to check if an input already exists.

Comment: You're using a DictWriter. If you use csv.DictReader(), you should be able to read existing data.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#module-contents

Comment: I am trying to check if the input I'm entering already exists in the file.

       reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
       for row in reader:
          if a == row['username']:

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: If a is the correct username, it should work. Can you share the code you're using?